# How to recognize touch gesture when screen is turned off

Tags: user-interface, mobile, gesture, screen-off

I have a Oneplus 6 and it has this super cool functionality wherein I can draw certain gestures on the turned off screen and it opens up apps and other stuff.
For example: drawing a circle switches on the flashlight, drawing an S opens the camera and a few others.
I also noticed that other phones do not have this functionality and wanted to build an app for the same.
I searched across the web and couldn't find a solution. The majority of the posts gave the following insights:

1. It couldn't be done since touch recognizer is off when screen is off.
2. We might have to alter the kernel for this and should be done from a manufacturer's standpoint.
3. Turn the screen black and recognize gesture. (Only works on OLED displays and its not what i want).

This is my use-case. If anyone has any knowledge on this matter please let me know how it can be done. Thanks in advance for the help.

PS - There are a lot of posts with this same topic. Please don't repeat those answers. If it's a NO please specify the exact reason why.

Comment: You already listed the reason why it is a NO yourself. What more do you need?

Comment: @cloned - I am not sure what you mean. I listed the the answers I saw on the internet regarding this. But I have this functionality on my phone. So I know there is a way to do it . I am also open to a definite NO, is what I am saying (with the proper justification).

Comment: You can do this on your phone because your manufacturer altered the kernel. So if you want to program it, do the same.